# Firebase error- E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, onesignal

What is this error, and how to fix?

It was working before I selected the Suggestion from android studio to upgrade the Onesignal dependency it is starting to give an error to firebase.

```
2020-04-25 12:47:59.876 24685-24972/com.appname.in E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb(Unknown Source:61)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:23)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzt.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.5:54)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzt.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.5:72)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.run(Unknown Source:12)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.1:6)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCall(com.google.firebase:firebase-installations@@16.2.1:350)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationInternal$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-installations@@16.2.1:323)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$5.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, this crash stopped occurring when I performed OneSignal library update and added Firebase Messaging to gradle. Here is my setup:

```
 dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.6'
    }
```

And on depedencies:

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.13.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'
```

By the way, the crash only occurred on the first app launch for me.